# How do I open html 5 files stored locally from the index.html page

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am doing a project on html5 & javascript using netbeans 7.3 with chrome integration. The file is stored locally.

If I run my project the index.html page opens and shows the buttons, labels & text boxes as expected. However one of the buttons is javascript programmed to open or launch another local html5 file. However I have been unsuccessful in getting this to work. The button I click is programmed to launch the secondary html5 file using URI file scheme.

Chrome reports an error saying 'No data received. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE'

IE 8 opens a separate window and reports 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'.

The secondary html5 file has only one line in it & that is the

tags with some text in between.

How do i get this to work in netbeans. I want to be able to program several other buttons in the index.html page to launch several other html files/pages.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to load data via XMLHttp, which doesn't support the file:/// scheme. In that case, you would need to upload your files to a web server, or run one locally. If that's not the case, please provide some code.

Comment: There is `HTML 5 Local Storage` which can be treated like a key/value object and is very easy to use.  It stores strings, not files, the browser manages it, and it persists until deleted by the user.  Then there is `HTML 5 FileReader`, which can read files selected by the user on his computer.  Which of these do you think you need?

Comment: I agree with Dan, you need to post more code, and ideally make a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problematic behavior.  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader says IE8 doesn't do `FileReader` but IE10 does.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. Dan, I am trying to launch a secondary html window in chrome. The file is just another html5 file located on my local machine. I am not using XMLHttp or anything fancy; just the URI scheme.